# Loan for outstanding school balance

Tags: loans, debt, school

I have a an outstanding school balance of around $7,000 dollars from the 2015-2016 school year and need it to be payed off in order to transfer to another 4 year university.  I wanted to know if there are any places in which I can acquire a student loan even though the balance is from a few years ago?  Or any other alternative that won't bite me in the butt in the long run.  I currently have a credit score of around 620 if that helps at all.

Comment: Why can't you get into another school with an existing student loan?

Comment: @DStanley Likely, first university won't release any records so OP can't transfer credits, etc.

Comment: Never mind I read that as loan balance - I see that OP owes the school now